# Casting List<Object> to List<CustomClass> does not throw error

Tags: java, list, casting, classcastexception

In a function, i am reading a set of json's from a table & assigning it to a List. This function then returns this list.

```
public List<JSONObject> getJsons(){
    SQLQuery query = sessionFactory.openSession().
            createSQLQuery("select json from JSONTable");

    List<JSONObject> jsonList = (List<JSONObject>)query.list();
    return jsonList;
}
```

Now I thought that an error would come up when i cast the result of query, i.e List(Object) to List(JSONObject) because we can't cast an Object to a JSONObject. Assuming it works in a similar way..

But this fails when i actually use the result of this function and gives the expected casting error, as shown below

jsonList here is the result of above function...

```
for(JSONObject json : jsonList){
    ...
}
```

If it were a single object it would have failed at the point of casting itself..why not in this case?

Comment: Generics. Erasure. It _does_ fail at the point of casting; the first cast does nothing. This is what you get for ignoring compiler warnings.

Comment: My Question is if i were doing the same for a single object, it would throw exception at the point of casting. But here it throws exception at the time of usage , not at time of casting...Why is the behaviour not same is my question...

Comment: As I said, the exception _is thrown_ at the time of casting. You need to read up on how generics in Java are implemented - i.e. erasure. If you ignore compiler warnings this is what happens.

Comment: The exception stack trace says it originated at the line of usage and not at point of casting.....hence my question...

Comment: The exception happens when the cast happens - in the foreach loop. Casting a generic type does nothing, but it will yield a compiler warning that the cast is not safe. This warning is emitted for exactly the reason that casting generics types will fail later in the code, when the generic type is resolved. Or it might not fail at all. Please do some research into how generics in Java work.